# Java IOException when deploying war file in wildfly 8

Tags: java, drools, java-io, wildfly-8

I'm trying to deploy a war file (Drools workbench) on wildfly 8, but getting the following exceptions :

```
    11:19:17,925 ERROR [org.eclipse.jgit.util.FS] (MSC service thread 1-2) Caught exception in FS.readPipe(): java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "bash" (in directory "C:\Users\bisharon"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047) [rt.jar:1.7.0_72]
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:617) [rt.jar:1.7.0_72]
        at org.eclipse.jgit.util.FS.readPipe(FS.java:431) [org.eclipse.jgit-3.7.1.201504261725-r.jar:3.7.1.201504261725-r]
        at org.eclipse.jgit.util.FS_Win32.discoverGitPrefix(FS_Win32.java:113) [org.eclipse.jgit-3.7.1.201504261725-r.jar:3.7.1.201504261725-r]
        at org.eclipse.jgit.util.FS.gitPrefix(FS.java:517) [org.eclipse.jgit-3.7.1.201504261725-r.jar:3.7.1.201504261725-r]
        at org.eclipse.jgit.util.SystemReader$Default.openSystemConfig(SystemReader.java:92) [org.eclipse.jgit-3.7.1.201504261725-r.jar:3.7.1.201504261725-r]
        at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.FileRepository.<init>(FileRepository.java:171) [org.eclipse.jgit-3.7.1.201504261725-r.jar:3.7.1.201504261725-r]
        at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.BaseRepositoryBuilder.build(BaseRepositoryBuilder.java:577) [org.eclipse.jgit-3.7.1.201504261725-r.jar:3.7.1.201504261725-r]
        at org.eclipse.jgit.api.InitCommand.call(InitCommand.java:113) [org.eclipse.jgit-3.7.1.201504261725-r.jar:3.7.1.201504261725-r]
        at org.uberfire.java.nio.fs.jgit.util.JGitUtil.newRepository(JGitUtil.java:104) [uberfire-nio2-jgit-0.7.3.Final.jar:0.7.3.Final]
        at org.uberfire.java.nio.fs.jgit.JGitFileSystemProvider.rescanForExistingRepositories(JGitFileSystemProvider.java:407) [uberfire-nio2-jgit-0.7.3.Final.jar:0.7.3.Final]
        at org.uberfire.java.nio.fs.jgit.JGitFileSystemProvider.<init>(JGitFileSystemProvider.java:371) [uberfire-nio2-jgit-0.7.3.Final.jar:0.7.3.Final]
        at org.uberfire.java.nio.fs.jgit.JGitFileSystemProvider.<init>(JGitFileSystemProvider.java:343) [uberfire-nio2-jgit-0.7.3.Final.jar:0.7.3.Final]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_72]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_72]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) [rt.jar:1.7.0_72]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526) [rt.jar:1.7.0_72]
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:379) [rt.jar:1.7.0_72]
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:373) [rt.jar:1.7.0_72]
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:445) [rt.jar:1.7.0_72]
        at org.uberfire.java.nio.file.api.FileSystemProviders.buildProviders(FileSystemProviders.java:65) [uberfire-nio2-api-0.7.3.Final.jar:0.7.3.Final]
        at org.uberfire.java.nio.file.api.FileSystemProviders.setup(FileSystemProviders.java:48) [uberfire-nio2-api-0.7.3.Final.jar:0.7.3.Final]
        at org.uberfire.java.nio.file.api.FileSystemProviders.resolveProvider(FileSystemProviders.java:104) [uberfire-nio2-api-0.7.3.Final.jar:0.7.3.Final]
        at org.uberfire.java.nio.file.FileSystems.newFileSystem(FileSystems.java:117) [uberfire-nio2-api-0.7.3.Final.jar:0.7.3.Final]
        at org.uberfire.java.nio.file.FileSystems.newFileSystem(FileSystems.java:83) [uberfire-nio2-api-0.7.3.Final.jar:0.7.3.Final]
        at org.uberfire.io.impl.AbstractIOService.newFileSystem(AbstractIOService.java:241) [uberfire-io-0.7.3.Final.jar:0.7.3.Final]
        at org.uberfire.backend.server.cdi.SystemConfigProducer$2.create(SystemConfigProducer.java:252) [uberfire-backend-cdi-0.7.3.Final.jar:0.7.3.Final]
        at org.uberfire.backend.server.cdi.SystemConfigProducer$2.create(SystemConfigProducer.java:187) [uberfire-backend-cdi-0.7.3.Final.jar:0.7.3.Final]
        at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:96) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:98) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:99) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
        at org.jboss.weld.proxies.FileSystem$1366014920$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getPath(Unknown Source) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:]
        at org.kie.uberfire.social.activities.server.SocialUserServicesExtendedBackEndImpl.buildPath(SocialUserServicesExtendedBackEndImpl.java:33) [kie-uberfire-social-activities-backend-6.3.0.Final.jar:6.3.0.Final]
        at org.kie.uberfire.social.activities.server.SocialUserServicesExtendedBackEndImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.buildPath(Unknown Source) [kie-uberfire-social-activities-backend-6.3.0.Final.jar:6.3.0.Final]
        at org.kie.uberfire.social.activities.persistence.SocialUserCachePersistence.<init>(SocialUserCachePersistence.java:42) [kie-uberfire-social-activities-backend-6.3.0.Final.jar:6.3.0.Final]
        at org.kie.uberfire.social.activities.persistence.SocialUserInstancePersistence.<init>(SocialUserInstancePersistence.java:16) [kie-uberfire-social-activities-backend-6.3.0.Final.jar:6.3.0.Final]
        at org.kie.uberfire.social.activities.server.SocialUserPersistenceProducer.setup(SocialUserPersistenceProducer.java:76) [kie-uberfire-social-activities-backend-6.3.0.Final.jar:6.3.0.Final]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_72]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_72]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_72]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_72]
        at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.invokeMethods(DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.java:89) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
        at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.postConstruct(DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.java:72) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
        at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.postConstruct(BasicInjectionTarget.java:95) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
        at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BeanInjectionTarget.postConstruct(BeanInjectionTarget.java:63) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:162) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
        at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:96) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:98) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:78) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
        at org.kie.uberfire.social.activities.server.SocialUserPersistenceProducer$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.toString(Unknown Source) [kie-uberfire-social-activities-backend-6.3.0.Final.jar:6.3.0.Final]
        at org.uberfire.backend.server.cdi.SystemConfigProducer.runPostConstruct(SystemConfigProducer.java:143) [uberfire-backend-cdi-0.7.3.Final.jar:0.7.3.Final]
        at org.uberfire.backend.server.cdi.SystemConfigProducer.afterDeploymentValidation(SystemConfigProducer.java:126) [uberfire-backend-cdi-0.7.3.Final.jar:0.7.3.Final]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_72]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_72]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_72]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_72]
        at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInjectionPoint.invokeOnInstanceWithSpecialValue(MethodInjectionPoint.java:93) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:266) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.java:125) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:253) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:232) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifyObserver(ObserverNotifier.java:169) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifyObservers(ObserverNotifier.java:128) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:102) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractContainerEvent.fire(AbstractContainerEvent.java:63) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDeploymentContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDeploymentContainerEvent.java:35) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AfterDeploymentValidationImpl.fire(AfterDeploymentValidationImpl.java:28) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.validateBeans(WeldStartup.java:396) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:85) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
        at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldStartService.start(WeldStartService.java:93) [wildfly-weld-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_72]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_72]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_72]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_72]
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:385) [rt.jar:1.7.0_72]
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:136) [rt.jar:1.7.0_72]
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028) [rt.jar:1.7.0_72]
        ... 74 more
```

I also tried to deploy it on another application servers such as : tomcat, jboss 7, but deployment has failed.
What could be the problem ? 
Should I configure something ?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an issue with the version of JGit used that can be safely ignored: [See this page for more info.](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/commit/ec6ec3b10fb1ef8dd73a499d0b1f7a7d711b84dd) It refers to an the issue described on the JGit github repo: "Avoid an IOException on Windows if bash is not in PATH."

Comment: Consider adding the context of the link to your answer as sometimes links can go stale.

Comment: Updated body to add some context as per the previous commenter's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Add bash to windows path  : in my case i just added it to my Path, and it's working :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\
```

Comment: How you got that Git folder?

Answer (score 0):

Why you do not use the ant configuration(build.xml) and deployer that come as recommended? It is tested and works fine.

As it is a Windows host, probably bash program is not there, but I am not sure why is left like this. You can ask in KIE development group.

Answer (score -1):

The war file you're trying to deploy tries to open bash command inside your home folder

```
run program "bash" (in directory "C:\Users\bisharon"):
```

you're running it on windows, so no bash is available there.

To fix this you need either to:

- recompile the source code so it is deployable on windows machine
- deploy it on a linux box (or Linux virtual machine)

Comment: How can it be fixed ? something in the configurations should be changed ?